# Is there a way to redefine a property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a base class that defines the `data` property as `any[]`. In a derived class I want to redeclare this property with a different type. So I am looking for some sort of the "[C# new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier)" feature in TypeScript. Is there a way to do something like this in TypeSctipt?

```
declare class MyBase { data: any[]; }
declare class MyData { }
declare class MyDerived extends MyBase { data: MyData; /* <--- problem */ }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this in TypeScript. It's basically a runtime constraint.

In C#, the `new` means that you're actually making a new name for the function that's only visible when going through an expression of the derived type, but using that name through expressions of the base type still see the base member (including in the base case implementation itself, critically).

In TypeScript/JavaScript, there's only one 'slot' in the object, and the derived class really is overwriting the base class's member. Odds are very high you'd be breaking the base class by overwriting that member, since there's no way for the base class to refer to the member it thought it had.

**Edit to add**: You *can* add specializations this way as long as they are actually sound (same as in C#, where you would usually only use the `new` keyword if you were breaking the base class shape). This restriction shouldn't actually be a problem if your types are coherent at runtime (i.e. you actually can used a Derived in place of a Base):

```
declare class Item {}
declare class SpecialItem extends Item { }

declare class MyBase { data: Item[]; }
declare class MyData { }
declare class MyDerived extends MyBase { data: SpecialItem[]; /* OK */ }
declare class MyDerived2 extends MyBase { data: number[]; /* not OK */ }
```

In your example, `data` in `MyDerived` would need to be a `MyData[]` (otherwise you're breaking the `MyBase` contract):

```
declare class MyBase { data: any[]; }
declare class MyData { }
declare class MyDerived extends MyBase { data: MyData[]; /* OK */ }
```

Comment: I am just working on a definition file for a 3rd party lib which changes types of properties in derived classes (javascript itself doesn't have such limitation leaving the consequences at the developer discretion). So you are saying there is no way to reflect this twist in TypeScript, aren't you?

Comment: Edited to add examples of where you can/cannot do this